# Is there a workaround when an underflow error occurs in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, underflow

I have a table containing in each row the a, b and c parameters to an exponential curve in the following formula:

```
a*exp(-b*x)+c
```

All columns are of type double precision.
I wish to sample each curve at a specific value of x and record its value in a new column. However, doing so causes an underflow error.

```
>update curve_by_wkt set samplepoint05 = a*exp(-b*0.05)+c;
ERROR:  value out of range: underflow
```

There is no way I can manually check which values of a, b, c are causing the calculation to fail. What I do know is that extreme precision is not needed, and that values outside a certain range are likely irrelevant.

I would like to know if there is any way I could get the calculation to complete, given my disregard for precision.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413940/how-can-i-prevent-detect-an-underflow-in-a-postgresql-calculation-that-uses-exp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function and catch an exception. You can raise your own error message:

```
create or replace function calculate_with_error
    (a double precision, b double precision, c double precision, x double precision)
returns double precision language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return a * exp(-b * x) + c;
    exception when numeric_value_out_of_range then 
        raise exception 'Value out of range for a = % b= % c= % x= %', a, b, c, x;
end $$;

select calculate_with_error(1, 1, 0, 10000);

ERROR:  Value out of range for a = 1 b= 1 c= 0 x= 10000
```

or set some default value:

```
create or replace function calculate_with_default
    (a double precision, b double precision, c double precision, x double precision)
returns double precision language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return a * exp(-b * x) + c;
    exception when numeric_value_out_of_range then 
        return 0;
end $$;

select calculate_with_default(1, 1, 0, 10000);

 calculate_with_default 
------------------------
                      0
(1 row)
```

Usage:

```
update curve_by_wkt 
set samplepoint05 = calculate_with_error(a, b, c, 0.05);
```

Answer (score -1):

A better solution (most likely) is to just use the `greatest` function to set a minimum value.  e.g.,

```
 greatest(a*exp(-b*x)+c, -50)
```

Most of the time 0 or some arbitrarily low number is good enough.

Comment: This doesn't help. `exp(-1000)` produces an underlflow error, and so does `greatest(exp(-1000),1e-15)`.